Why would a pointer declared const change in a lambda?
I am running gcc 11.4.0 under PopOS 22.04 LTS.  I am attempting to create a "conditional callback" with a lambda using references and pointers, like this:
#include <iostream>

struct A {
  int i;
};

class AProxy {
 private:
  A* const m_stored;
 public:
  AProxy(A& stored) : m_stored(&stored) {}
  void print() { std::cout << "i is " << m_stored->i << std::endl; }
};

class Holder {
 private:
  A& m_stored1;
  A& m_stored2;

 public:
  Holder(A& stored1, A& stored2) : m_stored1(stored1), m_stored2(stored2) {}
  void print() {
    std::cout << "i is " << m_stored1.i << std::endl;
  }
  void swap() {
    std::swap(m_stored1, m_stored2);
  }
  AProxy getstored1() { return {m_stored1}; }
  AProxy getstored2() { return {m_stored2}; }
};


int main() {
  A foo;
  A bar;
  foo.i = 5;
  bar.i = 6;

  Holder holder = {foo, bar};

  AProxy fooproxy = holder.getstored1();
  AProxy barproxy = holder.getstored2();

  auto foofunc = [fooproxy]() {
    AProxy copy = {fooproxy};
    copy.print();
  };

  foofunc(); //Prints 5
  holder.swap();
  foofunc(); //Prints 6?

  return 0;
}

My question is this: Since I told the compiler not to change what m_stored points to in AProxy, I would expect it to capture the reference to foo and hold on to it.
Why would it suddenly change out from under me like that?

A reference still points to a non const data. Applying const to a reference (nonsense, because it's always const) does not change a referenced type.

Since I told the compiler not to change what m_stored points to A* const m_stored - no, you did not. You fixed the address, but not a pointee. You might want it to point to a const: A const* m_stored.

"I told the compiler not to change what m_stored points to" And the compiler obeyed: m_stored still points to the same object that you initialized it to point to. The data inside that object might have changed, but m_stored did not.

Even if I change it to A const* though, it still prints 6.  I thought I wasn't swapping A.i, just the references to m_stored1 and m_stored2.  Does std::swap actually swap the data members within A?

@Brad "Even if I change it to A const* though, it still prints 6." -- This change tells the compiler not to change the pointed-to object when accessed through the pointer. holder.swap() does not make use of the proxies, so the prohibition does not apply.

Curious: why bring a lambda into the picture? The same phenomenon occurs if you invoke fooproxy.print(); instead of foofunc(); just with fewer copies (one from the capture, and one with each execution). I took a swing at your code and the two potential simplifications that stood out to me were removing Holder and removing the lambda (went from 54 to 28 lines). The former might be a challenge given the misunderstanding you were operating under, but the latter strikes me as relatively straight-forward. Did you expect that making copies would change something?

@JaMiT This was a minimal example, and I agree, it is contrived for what it does.  The actual code I'm working with is much more complicated and steps have to occur in a certain order that can change from case to case.

@Brad "This was a minimal example" -- Correction: this was an attempt at a minimal example. It probably is greatly simplified from where you started -- don't think I'm belittling your effort -- but there is more that could be done. I asked about the lambda because that is featured in the question's title and tags, as if it is a key element, yet it is fairly simple to eliminate the lambda from the example. (The classes could also be eliminated if one keeps applying simplification techniques, but they are less prominent in the text and tags.)

It's been said that an example can usually be done in a dozen lines. That holds true here as well. In case someone is interested in practicing minimalization  techniques, here is a 12-line goal for this question's code (blank lines won't show up in a comment, but I counted them anyway):
`#include 
int main() {
int foo = 5;
int bar = 6;
int* const fooproxy = &foo;
std::cout << "foo is " << *fooproxy << std::endl; //Prints 5
std::swap(foo, bar);
std::cout << "foo is " << *fooproxy << std::endl; //Prints 6?
}` (Other points of confusion might block you getting to this.)


Since I told the compiler not to change what m_stored points to in AProxy, I would expect it to capture the reference to foo and hold on to it.

That is exactly what it did.

Why would it suddenly change out from under me like that?

It isn't.
const applies to the thing on its left, unless there is nothing there, then it applies to the thing on its right.
Your use of const applies to the AProxy::m_stored pointer itself. You are telling the compiler to disallow changes to the pointer only.
But, you are not telling the compiler to disallow changes to the A object that the m_stored pointer is pointing at.
Only the pointer itself is const, not the object.
You are printing the value of foo.i, then swapping the value of foo.i with bar.i, then printing foo.i again. The pointers don't change, but the content of the objects they point to do change. That is why you see the result you are seeing.
You would have to make Holder hold references to const A objects, then swap() won't compile anymore. And you should make AProxy hold a pointer to a const A object, since it only ever reads from the object, never writes to it.
But, that still won't stop any other code that has direct access to foo and bar from making changes to them. The original objects are simply not const to begin with, even if you use const references/pointers to them. If you don't want the objects to ever change, make them const to begin with, eg:
const A foo{5};
const A bar{6};


Forgive me, I'm missing something simple here... how would swapping m_stored1 with m_stored2 change the values of the private data members inside A?

OK, I think I'm confusing references and pointers here.  You're right - thank you!

@Brad You are not swapping the references themselves (they can't be swapped). You are swapping the contents of the objects they refer to
